# Rails not routing to correct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a UserSessions controller for handling logins and logouts, but I have extended it to take allow unauthenticated users to enter an email address to receive a link to take a survey.

Here are my routes:

```
  resources :user_sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    post 'take_individual_survey' => 'user_sessions#take_survey', as: :take_individual_survey
```

This form below however is posting to user_sessions#new instead of user_sessions#take_survey
For some reason, I can route the form to other actions in the controller such as create, but the moment I try route the form to the intended path it just routes to #new.

```
= simple_form_for @member, url: take_individual_survey_path, method: :post do |f|
    =f.input :email, label: 'Please enter your email address', placeholder: 'john@doe.co.za', input_html: { class: 'respondent-email' }
    =f.submit 'Take Survey!', class: 'button'
```

Comment: have you added any before_filter in the user_seesions or in application controller?

Comment: @BachanSmruty oh my what a toolkit I am, it is the authentication mechanism redirecting to the login page

Comment: Yeah sometime we forgot to skip.. :)